# Unable to insert checked value into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I have a permissions table where the user can use a checkbox to give access or revert access for a URL link to a user with a particular role. So for this I've made it so that when a checkbox is pressed, the id of that checkbox and the role of the user are inserted in my database, but I'm unable to insert it in the database for some reason. I've tried the following code:

Controller Class:

```
public function permission()
    {
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $main['permissions']=$this->users_model->get_permission_array();
            $main['roles']=$this->users_model->get_roles_array();
            foreach($main['roles'] as $key => $val):
            $main['access'][$val['roles_id']]=$this->users_model->get_access_array(array('roles_id'=>$val['roles_id']));
            endforeach;
            $main['page'] = 'crm/users/permission';
            $this->load->view('crm/index', $main);
        }
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $loginid=false;
            foreach($main['roles'] as $key => $val):
            if(isset($_POST['roleid'.$val['roles_id']])){ 
                $this->users_model->clear_access(array('roles_id'=>$val['roles_id']));  
                foreach($_POST['roleid'.$val['roles_id']] as $id => $access): 
                    $data=array('roles_id'=>$val['roles_id'],'permissions_id'=>$access); 
                    $loginid=$this->users_model->permission_access($data);              
                endforeach;         
            }
            endforeach;
            if($loginid){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p>Permission updated Successfully.</p>');
                redirect('users/permission');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p>Error!! - Permission not updated.</p>');
                redirect('users/permission');
            }
        }
    }
```

Model Class:

```
function get_permission_array()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("crm_client_permissions");
    return $query->result_array();
}

function get_access_array($cond)
{
    $this->db->select("permissions_id");
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $query = $this->db->get("crm_client_role_access");
    return $query->result_array();
}

function clear_access($cond)
{
    return $this->db->delete("crm_clients_access",$cond);
}

function permission_access($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert("crm_clients_access",$data);
}

function get_roles_array($cond='')
{
    if($cond !='') $this->db->where($cond);
    $query = $this->db->get("crm_client_roles"); 
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

View Class:

```
<div <?php echo form_open_multipart('users/permission'); ?>>
<table>
<?php if($permissions) $i=0;foreach($permissions as $key => $permission): ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-center"><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $permission['page']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $permission['url']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach($roles as $rolekey => $role): 
              if($role['roles_id'] == 1)$checked = 'checked';
              if(in_array($permission['permissions_id'],array_map('current',$access[$role['roles_id']])))
              $checked = 'checked';
              else
              $checked = ''; ?>
            <td align="center"><div class="checkbox checkbox-success m-t-0"><input type="checkbox" class="accessbox"
            id="role<?php echo $rolekey ?>-<?php echo $key ?>" name="roleid<?php echo $role['roles_id']; ?>[]" 
            <?php echo $checked?> <?php echo ($role['roles_id'] == 1) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>   value="<?php  echo $permission['permissions_id']; ?>" />
            <label for="role<?php echo $rolekey ?>-<?php echo $key ?>"></label></div></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </table>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save Permission</button> <a href="<?php echo site_url('users/roles') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?> </div>
```

But here I always get Error!! - Permission not updated. in my view class which means it jumps to the else part of my controller. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems problem is here `$loginid=$this->users_model->permission_access($data);` and here `return $this->db->insert("crm_clients_access",$data);`.
My advise is to:

- use XDebug to debug your code and see what insert function returns and why.
- Also you may look for php log to see if there is any database errors. To use error logs you need to find php.ini config file and enable line 'error_log = /path/to/fige.log'.
- Also you may to lookup the database data to determine if insert function makes new row in table `crm_clients_access`, if it doesn't? you need to check your connection config to database host:port, so database process must be available at theese host:port.